# Future Warning with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script that reads in data from a csv file

The code runs fine, but everytime it runs I get this warning message:

```
 FutureWarning: A grouping was used that is not in the columns of the DataFrame and so was excluded from the result. This grouping will be included in a future version of pandas. Add the grouping as a column of the DataFrame to silence this warning.
```

the message points me to this code:

```
 formatted_df = {k: 'first' for k in df.columns} | {'Commodity': tuple, 'FixedPriceStrike': tuple, 'Quantity': tuple}
 group = (df['TradeID'].str.strip().ne('') | df['TradeDate'].str.strip().ne('')).cumsum()
 df = df.groupby(group, as_index=False).agg(formatted_df)
```

here is some sample data:

```
TradeID  TradeDate  Commodity  StartDate   ExpiryDate FixedPrice Quantity MTMValue
-------- ---------- ---------  ---------   ---------- ---------- -------- ---------
 aaa   01/01/2024   commodity1 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  10.00        10      100.00 
                    commodity2                         10.00        10          
 bbb   01/01/2024   commodity1 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  10.00        10      100.00 
                    commodity2                         10.00        10          
 ccc   01/01/2024   commodity1 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  10.00        10      100.00 
                    commodity2                         10.00        10
```

and here is the expected output :

```
TradeID  TradeDate  Commodity  StartDate   ExpiryDate FixedPrice Quantity MTMValue
-------- ---------- ---------  ---------   ---------- ---------- -------- ---------
 aaa   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  (10,10)   (10,10)   100.00 
 bbb   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  (10,10)   (10,10)   100.00 
 ccc   01/01/2024   (com1,com2) 01/01/2024  01/01/2024  (10,10)   (10,10)   100.00
```

I am unsure how to get rid of this warning, since I do not want to just add whatever grouping it is telling me to to the dataframe. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this warning or a different approach to getting the desired output?

Comment: The message tells you how to silence it. Create a new df where `group` is added as an additional column to `df`, then use that new df in the `groupby()` call.

Comment: Please add the original `df` in a format that we can execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened. You created an *external* grouper and after using it when grouping a DataFrame you threw away the group identifiers because of `as_index=False` parameter, so you lose the ability to track each group after aggregation. To prevent this, it is planned to store the grouper as a new column in such cases. That's what this warning is about.

I can see two ways to suppress FutureWarnigs without adding a new column to group by. One is to use [warnings.simplefilter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter):

```
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

The second option is to agree to use the grouper values as a new index during aggregation and then remove that index:

```
df = df.groupby(group).agg(formatted_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```